# What does OP stand for?

Tags: support, terminology

I know this is a simple question.  I see people leaving comments referring to the "OP".  By the context of how its used, I think it means the "asker" of the question.

Does OP stand for something?  Is there a SuperUser commonly used terms pages where things like that are defined?

Comment: Owner of Post :).

Comment: See also: [Stack Exchange Glossary - Dictionary of Commonly-Used Terms](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's short for **O**riginal **P**oster and refers to the person that started the discussion.

On Stack Exchange, this usually refers to the person that asked the question.

Answer (score 5):

It's a common internet term meaning "Original Poster" or "Original Post" depending on context.

In SE sites, it can refer to either the question or asker or, less likely, an answer or answerer depending on context.